# Projeto baseado no template spa VS2015. Como o serviço é gerado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Criei uma projeto usando o template SPA no Visual Studio 2015, para aprender e entender, mas achei esse exemplo bem complicado. Ainda não entendi onde o serviço é montado e carregado?

Comment: De qual serviço estamos falando?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, olá, quando clicamos no botão API do template ele abre uma tela com um grid já populado. Eu acredito que para popular o grid, é um serviço que faz isso, então é esse serviço. Eu, confesso, tô boiando que nem merda no Tietê.

Comment: Eu vou dar uma resposta, mas o melhor seria você fazer um curso para aplicar os conceitos. [Eu tenho um](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/), se interessar.

Comment: Achei interessante seu curso, o problema nesse exato momento seria como pagar mesmo, pois estou sem trampo, sabe como e´.

Comment: Tudo bem. Quando puder, [só me procurar](https://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O *template* SPA (Single Page Application, Aplicação de Página Única) é um modelo de aplicação cuja apresentação possui uma única página que realiza chamadas Ajax para uma API em ASP.NET Web API.

[O padrão Web API é explicado aqui](https://www.asp.net/web-api).

A diferença entre Web API e MVC é, basicamente, o tipo de requisição que cada padrão processa e os tipos de retorno. O MVC processa páginas em HTML, devolvendo normalmente HTML e alguns outros formatos, como XML, JSON, arquivos, e assim por diante, sendo normal a transição de página entre um endereço e outro.

Já o Web API implementa um padrão chamado REST, que o MVC implementa também, mas de forma mais especializada. Rotas do Web API podem devolver muitos outros formatos de arquivo (sendo JSON o mais comum), não sendo habitual devolver HTML (ainda que seja possível).

Isso é o que chamamos de microserviços: cada ponto de recurso (ou seja, cada endereço) desempenha uma pequena função bem específica. É ideal para implementar aplicativos de celular, por exemplo.

Por padrão, o projeto SPA do Visual Studio traz implementado o *framework* visual [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). O que ele faz é estruturar chamadas para essa Web API (que também faz parte do sistema) e a API devolve informação no formato JSON. Através de JavaScript, este *framework* recebe os dados, interpreta e produz um resultado visual sem carregar outra tela ou mudar de endereço.

Há vários outros *frameworks* que trabalham da mesma forma. Alguns exemplos:

- [Angular](https://angular.io/);
- [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/);
- [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/);
- [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Answer (score 3):

O template de SPA do ferramental do .NET Core lhe entrega 2 projetos em 1.
O primeiro é um WebAPI que preenchem a tabela que perguntou, esse projeto WebAPI faz o papel do server-side e lhe entrega/recebe dados.

O projeto SPA de fato (dependendo do framework que escolher) vai estar em uma pasta na raiz do projeto WebAPI. Este template utiliza uma implementação da Microsoft para pré-carregar os arquivos do site (SPA) esse pré-carregamento é benéfico devido as limitações que os sites SPA possuem com o SEO dos mecanismos de pesquisa.

É um bom startup, porém eu recomendo que você aprenda mais e faça o setup do seu projeto por conta própria.

Assista este vídeo sobre o template de SPA (em português):
https://youtu.be/_HFf8UUL25E

Comment: Valeu Eduardo, tenho assistido seus vídeos sim. É que tem umas coisinhas no projeto que está meio escuro de enxergar.